# Can a daily customer frequency filter be reduced to less than 2 subqueries when multiple timestamps exist for a given day and customer?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am trying to figure out if there is a more efficient way to get a count of frequent customers. The tricky part is I want to filter the customers based on payments per day while removing secondary records that occur for a given customer on more than one day. The dataset includes records for customers on the same day but at different times. I only want to count 1 and only 1 payment per day. 
For example, given the following values for (payment_id, customer_id, payment_date), I want a count 2

```
(17504, 341, '2007-02-16 17:23:14'),
(17505, 341, '2007-02-16 22:41:45'),
(17506, 341, '2007-02-19 19:39:56')
```

Once the records are grouped by customer and day, I want to filter on customers having more than 3 records and I want to return the count.

My current query is below. Is there another way to do this without so many nested subqueries?

```
SELECT (COUNT(*)) AS count_for_customers_with_more_than_3_visits
FROM (
  SELECT customer_id
  FROM (
    SELECT customer_id, date_trunc('day', payment_date) AS day
    FROM payments
    GROUP BY customer_id, day
  ) visits_by_day
  GROUP BY customer_id
  HAVING COUNT(day) > 3
) sub;
```

I'm using Postgres v9.6

[Data and query on SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ce2b3/26)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be more efficient, but it is shorter:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)) AS count_for_customers_with_more_than_3_visits
FROM (SELECT customer_id
      FROM payments
      GROUP BY customer_id
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT date_trunc('day', payment_date)) > 3
     ) sub;
```

Comment: Interesting, I kept getting errors when I tried using `COUNT` with `HAVING`. Thanks.